# Giving a static ip to an ssh server

Tags: networking, server, 18.04, ssh

i'm trying to turn my old pc into an ssh server and i want to give it a `custom static ip`. When i tried editing my network settings and giving my pc a custom ip such as `192.168.44.248` it won't connect to it via putty from windows and it says on my computer that my network is unmanaged thus preventing me from accessing most websites. If i use my automatically given ip e.g `192.168.1.10` my network works and i can successfully connect to the server via ssh from Windows. What should i do in order to use a static one in my ssh server? Do i have to change something in the `ssh_conf` file or in my network settings?

PS: I'm very new to Linux and especially working with ssh!

Comment: Probably you need to give the server an address like `192.168.1.*` so that it's actually on the same network...

Comment: This has to do with how Networking works and not Linux.  More than likely your network is setup with a DHCP server that your hosts are receiving with a netmask of 255.255.255.0, which means that ALL IPs on your network have to start with the same numbers up till the last octet.  Use the http://www.subnet-calculator.com/ to show you what valid IP addresses are for the same subnet being used.

Comment: @fkraiem hi and thanks for the reply. I tried creating a new network profile again using the ip 192.168.1.44 but when i select it, i get no access to the internet whatsoever and ubuntu is telling me again that the connection is unmanaged. I've changed my NetworkManager.conf file so that it has `managed=true` in it for that ip. Any ideas what i could be doing wrong?

Comment: "Network is unmanaged" just means Ubuntu is not automatically assigning IP and managing the network. You are the one who is doing the whatever managing is needed. Network should be set to unmanaged as soon as you change the what was the default set by Ubuntu.

Comment: IP addresses are usually assigned by your router. Check your router settings and see if a range of IP is reserved for automatic assignment. It any be 192.168.1.100 to 192.168.1.200. set your static IP out of this range. Some routers allow reserving a specific IP address for a specific device, defined by the device MAC address. If you do this in the router, change Ubuntu settings back to default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your configuration has to do with netmasking. It's a somewhat complicated subject, but the jist of it is this: the first 3 octets of an IP address on a home network (for the address 192.168.0.1, the first 3 octets are 192.168.0) are the "network" portion. The last octet is the host portion. For devices to communicate on a network, each must be on the same network portion. Even if they're directly connected by a single wire, if each is configured with a different network portion of their IPv4 address, they can't communicate. If you set your computers to something like 192.168.1.50 and 192.168.1.51, they should be able to communicate because they'll see they're on the same network.

You can change the length of the network/host portion of your netmask, but on a home network there's virtually never any reason to.

To learn more about netmasks and subnetting, see [This page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnetwork)

In short, only mess with the last block of numbers in your IP address against what's assigned by your router, and make sure you also don't take an address that's already taken by another device.

As for assigning a static IP address, you need a few more details than just the IP address you want. You'll also need to assign the Default Gateway (the IP address of your router) and the DNS Nameservers you would like to use (this can also be your router, or an arbitrary address like 8.8.8.8 for Google's public DNS) and you'll also have to specify the netmask, which in your case should be 255.255.255.0.

Comment: Thank you very much、i actually managed to find out most of this by trial and error. Your answer sums it up nicely! One last question, my server is now working but i can't reach certain websites when I'm using the network with the static ip. Is there a reason for that or did i mess something up?